# vscode interactive window with turtle module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I try to use the **interactive window** in `vscode` to run a very basic `turtle` program.

For example draw a single line:

```py
import turtle as ttl

ttl.shape('turtle')
ttl.speed(0)

# draw a line
ttl.forward(200)

ttl.mainloop()
print('done')
```

I exit gracefully (get the 'done' at the end).

When i try to run a second time in interactive mode i get an error.

```
Terminator                                Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\tests\test_stackoverflow.py in <cell line: 6>()
      24 # %%
      25 
      26 # a 2d graphics module
      27 import turtle as ttl
----> 30 ttl.shape('turtle')
      31 ttl.speed(0)
     33 # draw a line

File <string>:5, in shape(name)

Terminator:
```

- The code works fine outside of the interactive mode.
- If i comment out line 30 the error just moves to the next line.

I can run the code (`ctrl`+`enter`) once, but not a second time and strangely, if i run it a third time it works again. I have to `restart kernel` to be able to run the code the second time.

So my question is, Why does this happen and How can i get this to perfom normally (every time) ?

Comment: It also occurs in my interactive window or jupyter notebook, but it will not occur in the python file. This should be a design problem of jupyter extension. I will [submit it](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11509) to the developer for you, which should be the best solution.

Comment: @MingJie-MSFT,  thank you. That is most appreciated...

Comment: This isn't a problem with vscode or jupyter extension. It will occur in places other than vscode. This is a problem with package. It would be better to ask their developers to fix the problem

Comment: what do you mean "*a problem with package*" ?

Comment: The problems mentioned in issue was caused by theturtle package.